# JMS - producer is closed

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

The following code is trying to send a message on a queue using JMS.

```java
connection = jmsConnectionFactory.createConnection();
connection.start();

session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
Destination destination = session.createQueue(queueName);

MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(destination);
producer.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.PERSISTENT);
```

It works most of the time but while running a stress tests where many messages were sent in parallel, I found once the exception below:

```
Caused by: javax.jms.IllegalStateException: The producer is closed
        at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQMessageProducer.checkClosed(ActiveMQMessageProducer.java:195)
        at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQMessageProducerSupport.setDeliveryMode(ActiveMQMessageProducerSupport.java:136)
```

The exception is thrown in the `setDeliveryMode()`.
I have seen other posts about the same issue, but in my case I am not using shared sessions, nor shared connections.

I am running ActiveMQ 5.14.5.

Comment: Could you share more of your client code? Are you creating a connection, session, & producer for every message you send? If so, that's an anti-pattern you should definitely avoid.

Comment: I have seen many other posts complaining about issues caused by shared sessions.
I was thinking to use a connection pool, but I'd rather not reuse the session, unless there are known patterns that won't create problems.

Comment: There isn't so much more code. After setting the redelivery mode, it sends some messages and returns.

Comment: You certainly don't want to use a session concurrently between multiple threads, but a JMS connection is thread-safe so you probably only need 1 of those and then you can have a single session per thread rather than creating one each time you send a message. The same goes for the producer - one per thread.

Comment: I'm not as much concerned about what your code does after it calls `setDeliveryMode()` as I am about how all the variables are defined and how the containing class is actually used by the concurrent threads trying to send the messages.

Comment: The connection factory is configured by Spring. The class is running inside Alfresco (a content management system). There is a single instance of that class that is called by multiple threads when something happens in the repository. Long story short, there is a single instance of an object, initialised by Spring that is used in multiple threads and that executes the snippet of code in the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the code for `org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQMessageProducer` the `closed` variable (which is checked by the `checkClosed()` method at the top of the stack-trace) is initialized as `false` so something else has to be setting it to `true` for this exception to be thrown. From what I can see it is only set to `true` when the producer itself, the originating session, or originating connection is closed. It's possible that the connection and/or session is being closed in the background due to some other failure and this exception with the producer is the first visible symptom of that problem.

In any case, without at least some additional details about your code or ideally a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it's not really possible to draw a reliable conclusion.

Comment: Given the user states a stress test is in play one possibility is that they've exceeded a broker memory limit or some such and the connection dropped due to native thread creation failure or some such.